# MySQL Join When Record in Joined Table Does Not Exist

Tags: mysql, join

How I can join two tables when record in joined table doesn't exist. I'm tried something like this:

```
SELECT 
    Confessions.ID, Confessions.WriteTitle, Confessions.WriteArea,
    Confessions.POST_DATE, Votes.Type
FROM Confessions LEFT OUTER JOIN Votes ON Confessions.ID = Votes.PostID 
WHERE ForUser = :ForUser AND Status = :Status AND Votes.IP_Check = :IP_Check
```

but when record from votes with PostID like ID in Confessions doesn't exist MySQL gives back empty result for this record. isthere any other way?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A WHERE-condition on the inner table will change the the result to an Inner Join instead. You need to move this condition to the ON:

```
SELECT 
    Confessions.ID, Confessions.WriteTitle, Confessions.WriteArea,
    Confessions.POST_DATE, Votes.Type
FROM Confessions LEFT OUTER JOIN Votes 
  ON Confessions.ID = Votes.PostID 
 AND Votes.IP_Check = :IP_Check
WHERE ForUser = :ForUser AND Status = :Status
```

As a rule of thumb: Normally conditions on the Outer table are in `WHERE` while condition on the Inner table are in `ON`.